Can't serialize properly using a Custom ODataResourceSerializer when using $select or $expand
I created a custom OData Resource Serializer as part of the migration into dotnet core 8 and OData 9
This was mainly to maintain out previous syntax and support Geometry type from SQL spatial and NTS.
This works fine as long as we don't use $select or $expand. As soon as I use them the serializer method ODataResourceSerializer.WriteObjectInlineAsync graph object passes Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Query.Wrapper.SelectAll<NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Geometry> instead of NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Geometry and it doesn't seem possible to access the actual Geometry object from that. Although I'm fairly new to OData so I'm sure I'm missing something.
public override async Task WriteObjectInlineAsync(
object graph,
IEdmTypeReference expectedType,
ODataWriter writer,
ODataSerializerContext writeContext)
{
    try
    {        
        if (graph is NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Geometry geometry)
        {
            // Handle the serialization of the Geometry type here
            var serializedGeometry = geometry.SerializeGeomerty();
            await writer.WriteStartAsync(serializedGeometry);
            await writer.WriteEndAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            // Fallback to the default behavior
            await base.WriteObjectInlineAsync(graph, expectedType, writer, writeContext);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Log any exceptions for further inspection
        Console.WriteLine($"Error during serialization: {ex.Message}");
        throw;
    }
}


Without an answer I made it work using refection (kind of an ugly way to do this but works)

Typically, if you have $select and $expand, the result is a ISelectExpandWrapper. This interface contains a dictionary that you can retrieve all properties then you can build your instance using those properties.
Of course, you can use ResourceContext to get an instance.
Since you have a solution, would you please share more details about your solution that can help others with the similar requirement.

@SamXu thanks that and using an ObjectInstance made it work properly.
